# Java: equals and hashCode methods contract

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

The author of the question says the answer is D, but I wonder why the answer should not be C??

Q: Which statement is true about the code that can fill in the blank?

```
class Sticker {
  public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return____________ ;
 }
}
```

A. It must return false.
B. It must return true.
C. It can return either true or false.
D. None of the above.

---

**EDIT 1**:

The answer and explanation for it given by the author is following:
If two instances of a class have the same hash code, they might or might not be equal. The reverse is not true. If two objects are equal, they must have the same hashcode in order to comply with the contracts of these methods. However, in this case, the answer is none of the above because the method can’t simply return true or false. Based on the rules of equals(), if null is passed in, the result must be false. If an object identity is passed in, the result must be true due to reflexivity. As a result, Option D is correct.

---

**EDIT 2**:
May be the author means the following by his explanation given above:
I think may be the author wants to say that if we return `true` from the `equals(Object)` then there is a possibility that somebody could pass a `null` in the `equals(Object)` in which case it will be contradicting the return value `true` as based on `null` argument being passed the return value should be `false` not `true`. Similarly, if we return `false` then there is a possibility that a `Sticker` object identity is passed and then it'll again be contradicting. So basically we can't really fill in the blank with either `true` or `false`. May be that was why author said the answer was D.

Comment: What do you think? It looks like it is a homework that should by done by yourself

Comment: Dear Jens, I know the answer but I am not able to understand the explanation given. The author of the question says the answer is D, but I am not able to understand that why the answer is not C? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, let me post the answer with explanation too.

Comment: I also expected C

Comment: I have added the explanation given by the author for the option D in the EDIT part of the question. Please take a look. I think the answer should be C based on equals and hashCode methods contract and also based on what the explanation is given by the author.

Comment: The author sounds like he’s has a few nuts and bolts loose. Equals always has to return something (unless you throw an exception, but please don’t), and the author even states that in their answer.

Comment: Correct, that's why I thought the author wanted to say that the answer was C but mistakenly printed D as an answer.

Comment: I would ask the author, he states that you can’t simply return true or false, and then explains why with a reason that is a contradiction.

Comment: I think option C is supposed to mean that "the method body could be either `return true;` or `return false;`", i.e. the method could return either true or false as a constant value.

Comment: @Radiodef Correct, I think that now too. Based on that option D is the correct option.

Answer (score 3):

The author has poorly written the answer options. It is clear from their explanation that their answer choices would be better written as:

> A. It should always return false. B. It should always return true. C. Returning true or returning false are always both correct. D. None of the above.

The question might also benefit from a rewrite:

> Assuming the code which fills in the blank correctly fulfills the contract of the equals() method, which statement below is always true?

The author has committed two grievous infractions against computer science

1. **Keyword violation**. 'Return' is a keyword, and it is colossally stupid to use 'return' when you really mean 'return correctly'. Sentence = *must attempt to explain pointer logic to a 300-person class of freshmen* This particular violation is what makes it so incomprehensible, since a boolean function can obviously return true or false.
2. **Boolean logic violation**. Booleans can be true or false. Therefore, a function returning a boolean can either always return true, always return false, or sometimes return one and sometimes the other. To give 4 answer choices to a boolean problem is a violation of the nature of booleans. This violation is compounded by the abuse of the keyword 'return', but in and of itself it should be a crime. Sentence = *pair-program in C++ with an intern whose only CS education is a React bootcamp*

Comment: that's right question is poorly written because it can be `return o!=null && ((o == this) || ((o.hashCode() == this.hashCode()) && (... other fields comparision ...)));`